# What are different options to debug in symfony2

Tags: symfony, debugging, console

I am developing a symfony2 application.

Recently i came across this command

```
php app/console router:debug
```

which was very useful to me!
Then i also came across

```
php app/console container:debug
```

which was also very helpful.

Where can i find the list of all such commands?

I tried to find them in symfony cooknook but all i could find is http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html

Comment: It varies depending on the bundles you have included in your project. Doctrine has dump commands, FOS has helper commands...etc Giving a precision answer for "Symfony" is difficult as Symfony is now very modular and so commands are in bundles and thus vary massively. The most useful of all Symfony de-bugg tools is, profiler - but it is only applicable to web requests (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

From your command line you can simply run:

```
php app/console list | grep debug
```

If on Windows, just run

```
php app/console list
```

and manually search through the results.